# Remote web based testing and debugging service for iOS and Android application

Tags: android, iphone, ios, logging, crash-reports

Are there any good tools for getting statistics about applications released to testers? So far I have found the http://www.hockeyapp.net/ - I went through tutorials and it seems to be nothing more then the crash log collector and new versions notifier. I would like to collect also debug logs, have possibility to configure application, see number of testers, time they spend by testing, get information about devices they used, possibly see the network traces of my application.

I understand it of course will need more integration of the "service SDK" with our code, but this we can accept.

Regards,
STeN

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is , can create a api that can accept log string,date time, user id etc and on device side you can create one myLog function which calls this api ,, so at runtime you can debug what each user is doing.